# Вопрос по строковым литералам

Tags: c++, строки

Почему вот это приводит к ошибке времени исполнения:

```
int main()
{
    char *p = "string";
    p[1] = 'p';
    return 0;
}
```

И почему код вообще компилируется, если в выражении `char *p = "string";` тип слева равен `char *`, а тип справа равен `const char*`, или я что-то путаю?

Comment: А разве компилятор не выдал варнинг?

Comment: да, выдал, но всё же скомпилировал. Но почему?

Comment: Потому что это разрешено стандартом в целях сохранения совместимости с Си. Но варнинг *deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'* говорит о том, что в следующей версии стандарта С++ эта операция будет запрещена и вот тогда компилятор будет выдавать ошибку.

Comment: @zed Емнип, это вообще запрещено начиная с С++11.

Comment: При загрузке программы в память ОС размещает константы в защищенной от записи  области памяти. Поэтому в `p[1] = 'p';` возникает прерывание по некорректному доступу к памяти. Если надо модифицировать строки, то их нужно размещать в инициализированных массивах. Например, так:  `char p[] = "string";`

Comment: Что значит "выдал, но всё же скомпилировал"? Если ваш компилятор в процессе компиляции выдал хотя бы одно требуемое стандартом языка диагностическое сообщение, то в мире С++ это называется  "**не** скомпилировал".

Comment: Поправьте меня, если я не прав. Если компиляция программы в итоге выдала исполняемый файл, при этом сообщив мне о том, что я написал что-то, что может привести к ошибке(warning), то это значит, что код скомпилировался. Например выражение `for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)` выдаёт предупреждение `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`, но выдаёт мне .exe файл, то есть компиляция прошла успешно, синтаксис языка не нарушен.

Answer (score 0):

У указателя нет модификатора const, поэтому, формально, изменение в области памяти по этому указателю не запрещено. Например в следующий момент вы можете присвоить указателю адрес на область памяти с неконстантным содержимым. Поэтому данный код не вызывает ошибки времени компиляции. Однако вызывает ошибку времени выполнения, потому что в данным момент указатель ссылается на неизменяемые данные. С++ язык со слабой типизацией, поэтому такие "фокусы" возможны.

Comment: Вообще в c++ это это должно быть не возможно, просто нужно как-то поддерживать совместимость с уже написанными программами на си, где запись `char *p = "string";` была возможной, поэтому конкретно для такой записи сделали исключение, и вместо ошибки выдают предупреждение и делают неявный каст.

Answer (score 0):

Код приводит к "ошибке времени исполнения" (а точнее - к *неопределенному поведению*), потому что в языке C++ строковые литералы являются немодифицируемыми.

При этом в инициализации

```
char *p = "string";
```

тип слева - `char *`, а тип справа `const char[7]`. Такая инициализация является ошибочной в языке C++11 и позже.

В более ранних версиях языка (C++98 и С++03) такая инициализация являлась корректной, благодаря специальному исключению, сделанному именно для таких случаях в спецификации array-to-pointer conversion.

Если вы используете современный компилятор С++, то скорее всего у вас этот код НЕ компилируется, а вы сами этого просто не заметили, т.е. проигнорировали диагностическое сообщение компилятора.